# Data sync between two local Mysql databases in different system in same netwrok

Tags: mysql, data

I am using mysql as database for my application and for the purpose of fail over and I need to sync the data from  one local mysql database in system one to other local database in system 2 connected through same network.So I want to know how to connect local database in other system and sync data automatically

Answer (score 1):

You need MySQL replication.

Here is the official documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html

I like to use step by step guides, so here's a more simple explanation: http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/get-mysql-replication-up-and-running-in-5-minutes

Those docs should work for MySQL 5.X and 8.X.